# Allow user to read if discussionBoard/userId array conatins auth.uid | Firebase realtime db security rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have Firebase Realtime db structure as .

```
.
└── root/
    ├── abc
    ├── xyz
    └── my_target/
        └── target_id/
            ├── msg: "hi"
            └── userIds : [12, 23, 34]
```

now I want user to read `my_target` data if  `my_target/userIds conains auth.uid`

I tried doing this but this is not allowing user to read

```
{
  "rules": {
    "my_target": {
      "$target_id": {
       ".read": "auth != null && root.child('my_target/' + $target_id+ '/userIds').val().contains(auth.uid)",
        ".write": true 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For eg I want this code to be allowed to read

```
/my_target/target_id
```

while using uid that is present in userIds array.
I was expecting it to work, but it didnt allowed even if I put userId same as one in the userId array.

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the minimal **code** that doesn't work the way you expect it against these rules.